# How to form an expression to select all n-th depth descendants of specific type(s)

Tags: php, html, xpath

I have struggled around an xpath expression to find the n-th depth descendants of specific types.

The problem broken down could be described like that: Find all `<section>` ***or*** `<article>` elements with a depth of 2 ignoring any other elements in the path. In other words: Depth is only counted on `section` or `article` tags.

```
<body>
  <main>

    <section>
      <div>

        <article>this is to be selected
          <div>
            <section></section>
          </div>
        </article>

      </div>
    </section>

    <article>
      <div>
        <div>

          <section>this is to be selected
            <div>
              <section></section>
            </div>
          </section>

        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

  </main>
</body>
```

All my bad and confused tries do not solve the problem in the least and are not considerable. Is there any expression fitting my needs?

Handling `article` ***or*** `section` would be great, however, any solution by approximation as handling a document restricted to sections would be a first step as well. Even the latter I could not come close to yet.

An alternative solution in PHP is welcome. I know to traverse an XML Document, however, I am looking for a short eloquent expression.

Comment: Please feel free to edit my question if you can improve my English expression to be more understandable. I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right you're looking for an expression along the lines of:

1. `//*` any element at any depth
2. `[self::article or self::section]` that is either article or section
3. `[*/*]` that has a child element with a child element
4. `[not(*/*/*)]` and *doesn't* have a child element with a child element with a child element

Combine to get articles and sections that are grandparents, but not great-grandparents:

```
//*[(self::article or self::section) and */* and not(*/*/*)]
```

#### Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$query = '//*[(self::article or self::section) and */* and not(*/*/*)]';

foreach ($xpath->query($query) as $node) {
    echo $dom->saveXML($node), "\n";
}
```

#### Output:

```
<article>this is to be selected
          <div>
            <section/>
          </div>
        </article>
<section>this is to be selected
            <div>
              <section/>
            </div>
          </section>
```

---

To extend this to n levels of descendants generate the xpath expression dynamically:

```
$descendants_depth = 2;
$xfrag = rtrim(str_repeat("*/", $descendants_depth), "/");
$query = "//*[(self::article or self::section) and $xfrag and not($xfrag/*)]";
```

Comment: Thanks so far! Looks interesting and seems to solve the particular given case. If the 3rd level is to be fetched, the condition is `and */*/* and not(*/*/*/*)` isn't it? So I could dynamically generate the string expression on any depth level.

Comment: No problem, that's the minor matter. :) A really great, short and eloquent expression! For my understanding: `//*[self::article]` means: *any element that is* while `//*[article]` means: *any element having an article child **or** beeing self an article*. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

If I take you literally you would like to find any `section` or `article` that has exactly one ancestor that is a `section` or an `article.`

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$expression = 
  '//*[
    (self::article or self::section) and 
    count(ancestor::*[self::article or self::section]) = 1
   ]';

foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $node) {
  echo $document->saveXML($node), "\n";
}
```

The Xpath Expression

- Fetch any element node
  `//*`
- that has an `article` or an `section` on the `self` axis (The `self` axis contains the current node itself)
  `//*[self::article or self::section]`
- and have one ancestor element node
  `//*[(self::article or self::section) and count(ancestor::*) = 1]`
- that has an `article` or an `section` on the `self` axis
  `//*[(self::article or self::section) and count(ancestor::*[self::article or self::section]) = 1]`

Axes define the initial set of nodes that the location path uses. The default axis is `child`, so `article` is actually `child::article`.

This approach can be used to fetch the level for a specific node as well.

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//*[self::article or self::section]') as $node) {
  $level = $xpath->evaluate('count(ancestor::*[self::article or self::section])', $node);
  echo $node->localName, ', level: ', $level, "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
section, level: 0
article, level: 1
section, level: 2
article, level: 0
section, level: 1
section, level: 2
```